# How can I make time series data with multiple lines?

Tags: r, time, time-series, data-visualization

I want to plot the yield of sugarcane, coconut and rice in time. But I got this output:

![My output plot][1]

Comment: Hi Emily. It wasn't really easy to access the data. I bet you get an answer within 10 minutes if you'd share a portion of your data e.g. `dput(head(data, 10))`.

Comment: I edited the question. Please, I really need help, I've been trying for hours.

Comment: Some hints upfront. 1 You get stacked data points for a year because you miss month and day to differentiate the similar years. 2 I'd suggest to `log()` the yield to put them on the same scale. Something like this already works: `ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = log(Yield), colour = Crop, group = Crop)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_minimal()`. Don't know if you can add month and/or day to your years...

Comment: I tried this one : lubridate::ymd(data$Year, truncated = 2) but it did not work. Can you help me to obtain similar to graph above?

Comment: If the original data doesn't contain the month and days (as it seems by looking at the samples on the linked website) its difficult to put the data in right order. Just adding made up numbers would very likely mess up the order.

Comment: An example of potential wrong order but right plotting would be: `ggplot(data %>% group_by(Year, Crop) %>% mutate(n=cur_group_id(), nn=cumsum(duplicated(n)+1), yy=ymd(paste(Year, nn, "01")), n=NULL, nn=NULL), aes(x = yy, y = log(Yield), colour = Crop, group = Crop)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_minimal()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data should be `aggregate`d first, since it has multiple entries for the same date and crop, I assume you want `sum` as aggregation function. In the data argument I use `transform` to apply `ISOdate` (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060885/6574038)) as well as define a numeric vector for `pch` and `color` for plotting.

```
a <- aggregate(Yield ~ ., 
               transform(data, Year=ISOdate(Year, 1, 1, 0),
                               clr=as.integer(factor(Crop)) + 1), FUN=sum)
```

Then, `plot` and empty base plot, I suggest `log`arithmic might be suitable with you data. Next, loop `lines` over the crops using `by`. Finally place a nice `legend` that's it.

Here a basic version:

```
plot(Yield ~ Year, a, log='y', type='n')
by(a, a$Crop, \(x) with(x, lines(Yield ~ Year, type='b', col=clr, pch=clr)))
legend('right', legend=unique(data$Crop), col=unique(a$clr), pch=unique(a$clr))
```

[image]

Comment: It gave this error: Error: unexpected input in "by(a, a$Crop, \"

Comment: @EmilyEssa Update your R, or if not possible, use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Yield, colour = Crop, group = Crop)) + geom_smooth() + xlab("")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).