# How to change integer year to date year?

Tags: r, lubridate

In my dataset, class(data$Year) is integer. How can I change the year as Date year?

```
data$Year <- as.Date(as.character(data$Year), format = "%Y")
data$Year <- year(data$Year)
```

I tried this one but this time `class(data$Year)` gave numeric output. How can I transform it as Date object?

Comment: You can use `lubridate::ymd(data$Year, truncated = 2)` i.e. `lubridate::ymd(2001, truncated = 2)#
[1] "2001-01-01"`

Answer (score 0):

A `"Date"` class always is a full date, like `"2022-04-29"`. A value `"2022"` of class `"Date"` is not possible.

You may conveniently convert it to, say, January first using `ISOdate` and `as.Date`. The latter is only important if you really want `"Date"` class and not `"POSIXct"`.

```
x <- 2020:2022

ISOdate(x, 1, 1, 0) |> as.Date()
# [1] "2020-01-01" "2021-01-01" "2022-01-01"
```